# Javascript Wrong tr info creating dynamic tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that a user can fill out.

What i want to be able to do is allow to user to add more feilds if needed.

All works wells expect for one small part i cannot seem to get around. I have spent the last couple days trying to figure it out and its driving me crazy.

Javascript Code

```
<script>
var ed = 1;
function new_education()
{
    ed++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ed;
    var delLink = '<a class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px" href="javascript:deled('+ ed +')" > Delete Education ' + ed + ' </a>';
    document.getElementById('educationtr').innerHTML = '<th colspan="4" style="background-color:#b0c4de;">Education ' + ed + '</th>';
    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('educationtpl').innerHTML + delLink;
    document.getElementById('education').appendChild(div1);
}
function deled(eleId)
{
    d = document;
    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
  var parentEle = d.getElementById('education');
    parentEle.removeChild(ele);
    ed--;
}
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<legend>Education</legend>
<div id="education">
<table border=3>
<tr><th colspan="4" style="background-color:#b0c4de;">Education 1</th></tr>
<tr><td><label>School Name</label><input  type="text" name="schoolname[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
<td><label>Degree Type</label><input  type="text" name="degreetye[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
<td><label>Degree Field</label><input  type="text" name="degreefield[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
</tr></table>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:new_education()" > Add New Education </a>

<div id="educationtpl" style="display:none">
<table border=3>
<tr id="educationtr"></tr>
<tr><td><label>School Name</label><input  type="text" name="schoolname[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
<td><label>Degree Type</label><input  type="text" name="degreetype[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
<td><label>Degree Field</label><input  type="text" name="degreefield[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

jsfiddle example not working however http://jsfiddle.net/811yohpn/

Working Example: http://thenerdservice.com/addtest.php

What I would like to happen is each new table added will get a new heading "Education 2", "Education 3" etc but that does not happen.

What happens is when the button is hit to add new table the tr data will appear correct.

If you hit it once more it will increment the tr data however the delete buttons stay 
correct.

If you hit the button more times the top tr data will continue to increment however the reat of the added tr data stays "Education 2"

Thank you

Comment: [Corrected question fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/811yohpn/1/).

Comment: Once again: elements ID **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest is to rewrite `new_education` function using jQuery (I have tried to save most part of original code, but it wasn't so easy) fixing this problem with multiple same IDs.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/811yohpn/2/).

```
function new_education() {
    ed++;
    var newDiv = $('#education div:first').clone();
    newDiv.attr('id', ed);
    var delLink = '<a class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px" href="javascript:deled(' + ed + ')" > Delete Education ' + ed + ' </a>';
    newDiv.find('tr:first th').text('Education ' + ed);
    newDiv.append(delLink);
    $('#education').append(newDiv);
}
```

Note: I also changed HTML, removing unnecessary extra table and wrapping first one with `<div id="1"></div>`:

```
<legend>Education</legend>
<div id="education">
    <div id="1">
        <table border=3>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#b0c4de;">Education 1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>School Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="schoolname[]" maxlength="30" size="30"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Degree Type</label>
                    <input type="text" name="degreetye[]" maxlength="30" size="30"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Degree Field</label>
                    <input type="text" name="degreefield[]" maxlength="30" size="30"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<a class="js-addNew btn btn-info" href="javascript:new_education()"> Add New Education </a>
```